# how to attach multiple files with comments in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, comments, attachment

I wanto attach multiple files with comment in wordpress.  The comments section after the post should attach multiple files with comment.  Any code, method or plugin related to it.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this plugin. It would allow you to `attach` files.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/comment-attachment/

Comment: So what is the issue when using this plugin?

Comment: this upload only one file to comment

Comment: I have used this plugin and it does support adding multiple files to a single post. Check this screenshot of my `wordpress` site where I have uploaded `multiple files` for demo:  https://ibb.co/f9gkVa

Answer (score 0):

Comment attachment plugin has option to upload single file not multiple file